# Two columns for password in Laravel for login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two password column one is password and other in temp_password, user can login with either password or temp_password for that i'm using following code:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
    echo "User Logged In";
} else if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'temp_password' => \Crypt::encrypt(request('password'))])) {
    echo "User Logged in";
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Credentials";
}
```

i'm getting this error :

> Undefined index: password", exception: "ErrorException"

if i remove else if part it is working properly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which part do you remove to make your code work ?

Comment: @Atchiiii: i removed else if part it was working but i want else if part also so that user can login with both the password, a have decryped the password in temp_password column.

Comment: @sta: i tried this it is still giving me this error : Undefined index: password", exception: "ErrorException",…

Comment: Ensure your keys are named `email` and `password`. I.e: `temp_password` rename to `password`.

Comment: @gclark18: email, and password are there and working but when i try to use temp_password then i'm facing this issue

Comment: Exactly, do not use `temp_password`. `Auth::attempt()` expects an associative array containing an `email` key and a `password` key;.

Comment: @gclark18: but then how will i compare it with temp_passwod field in database, current scenario is if the password does not matches with the password column then user can try login with default password which is provided to them and that will match with the temp_password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Auth::Attempt()` method expects an array with `email` and `password` indexes.

[@Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

If you dont provide them, it will fail. 'password' is not a dynamic field to it, it must be password. You need to do it manually for the temp_password field

```php
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) { 
    echo "User Logged In";
} else {
    $user = User::where('email', '=', request('email'))->first();
    if (!$user || !Hash::check(request('password'), $user->temp_password);) {
       echo "Incorrect Credentials";
       return;
    }
    Auth::guard()->login($user);
    echo "User Logged In";
}
```